# LINQ to SQL Server: different speed for the same query on different column

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am developing a C# application that use a SQL Server (2008 R2) through LINQ.

I have a query like this:

```
datacontex.Table.Where(e => e.id == id).OrderByDescending(e => e.<item>).FirstOrDefault();
```

The issue is that the query performs different speed based on the different "item" I use.

I mean this: query runs in 1ms if item is "item1", but runs in 50-200ms if item is "item2"

All "id", "item1" and "item2" are non clustered index.
The only difference is that item1 is a datetime, item2 is a int.

The only way to have both query to run fast is to alter the "id" index to include also "item2".

Why this happens?

**EDIT**: some other details about the table.
The table contains up to 100 different, non unique, "id".
For each id there are up to 5000 rows. Item2 is not unique, but the pairs (id, item2) is unique. Example:

```
ID      ITEM2           ITEM1
 1        1     <auto generated timestamp>
 1        2
 1        3
[...]    [...]
 1      5000

 2      3000
 2      3001
 2      3002
[...]    [...]
 2      8000

100     1001
100     1002
100     1003
[...]    [...]
100     6000
```

Comment: Could be the variance in the values.  Does your `item1` tend to be one of a few values while `item2` is more diverse?

Comment: item1 is a numeric id and can be duplicated up to 100 times in a table (each table contains up to 500.000 items); item2 is a autocreated timestamp.

Comment: This is hard to answer based on interpretations, since we cannot see the actual data. My guess is that the item2 you pass, is not of the exact type (smalldatetime, date, datetime, datetime2 or even passed as string) and is implicitly converted, leading to loss of index.

Comment: Forgive me, I messed up in the first comment: item1 (the "fast") is a timestamp, item2 (the "slow") is a int16.

Comment: than it is surely the recordset, for the item1 you probably get more tuples, while the timestamp is more likely just returning only a few results.

Comment: And this can motivate a 50-200 times slower response?

Comment: Use SQL Server Profiler to see what SQL query is being sent to SQL Server, and to examine the execution plan. That will clearly show you where the difference is.

Comment: I use activity monitor on SSMS and execution plan seems to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting problem. I would expect the int column to sort faster than the datetime, as there are fewer bytes per key, hence less IO on the non-clustered index. Maybe your data has lots of `item2` rows with the same value?

I would suggest isolating the SQL that is generated and running it in Management Studio. The SSMS performance tools may reveal something, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650689.aspx.

Comment: I edited my original question to add some details about the table.